# Submitting Form Post as ARRAY, Can't seem to set variables to work with

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I'm trying to submit multiple rows on one form.
Naming convention for values is `form[ValueName][]`

```
$rows = 2;
for($i = 0; $i <= $rows - 1; $i++){


    echo "<tr><td align=left><Select class='required' name=form[PlanType][]>" . $PlanList . "</select></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><Input class='required' style='max-width:455px;' name='form[PlanDescr][]' value='" . $PlanDescr . "'></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><select class='required' name='form[EmployeeId][]'>" . $dd . "</select></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><input class='required' type=text style='text-align:right;max-width:100px;' name='form[RepNum][]' value='" . $RepNum . "'></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><input class='required' type=text style='text-align:right;max-width:100px;' name='form[OfficeNum][]' value='" . $OfficeNum . "'></td>";
    echo "<td align=center><input type=checkbox name='form[Main][]' value='1' " . ($main?"checked":"") . "></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><select class='required' name='form[Schedule][]'>" . $Schedule . "</select></td>";
    echo "<td align=left><input class='required' type=text style='text-align:right;max-width:100px;' name='form[NumMos][]' value='" . $NumMos . "'></td>";

    echo "<td align=left><input class='required' type=text style='text-align:right;max-width:100px;' name='form[PctPmt][]' value='" . $PctPmt . "'></td>";

    echo "<td align=left><input class='required' type=text style='text-align:right;max-width:100px;' name='form[FrontPmt][]' value='" . $FrontPmt . "'></td></tr><tr class='spacer'></tr>";
}
```

I'm saving to a DB and sending to API.
When it was just one row as a simple POST it worked fine, but trying to submit multiple as an array, I get an empty array returned when trying to echo each value during debugging.

Variable setting in submit Function:

```
$count = count($_REQUEST['form']['PlanType']);



for($i = 0; $i <= $count - 1; $i++){
    //Pull, Sanitize, and Set URL Variables
    $residualsClient = new ResidualsAPI();
    $mydb = DBManagerFactory::getInstance("formdbconfig");
    $EmployeeId = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["EmployeeId"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $PlanType = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["PlanType"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $PlanDescr = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["PlanDescr"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Schedule = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["Schedule"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $FrontPmt = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["FrontPmt"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    $PctPmt = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["PctPmt"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
    $OfficeNum = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["OfficeNum"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $RepNum = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["RepNum"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $NumMos = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["NumMos"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $PlanId = filter_input_array($_POST["form"]["PlanId"][$i],FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}
```

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong?
Am I missing something stupid and simple?

Thanks in Advance,

Steven

Comment: Can you create a minimum example that still produces your error?

Comment: [Minimal, viable code](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please!

Comment: use print_r($_POST); and see what it is printing in your php before count.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need second empty [] in inputs name attribute, just form[name]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the empty [], i.e. name='form[Schedule]'. Then you get associative array from $_POST["form"].

```
$Schedule = filter_var($_POST["form"]["Schedule"],FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far. I've been able to get the form values. But, the filter_input_array isn't allowing the variables to be set. If I just use $_POST["form"]["Schedule"]; I can get them set. Is there a different way I can sanitize these?

Comment: You should use filter_var Es.http://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_sanitize_string.asp I.E.    filter_var($str,FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING,FILTER_FLAG_NO_ENCODE_QUOTES);